# Including iOS 6 properties in an object for an iOS 4.3 backwards-compatible app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, ios6

I'm adding some iOS 6 features to an existing app -- specifically, the built-in facebook integration.  However, I need my app to retain backwards compatibility with iOS 4.3.

In most code, I understand how to handle this using respondsToSelector; I also understand to weakly link the Social and Accounts frameworks so they're only loaded if available.

What I don't know, though, is this: In order to enable the Facebook integration, I need to add a property to my "ShareViewController" -- which handles all the sharing for my app -- to hold the composition sheet, i.e.:

`SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;`

However, SLComposeViewController is a class that exists only in iOS6.  So essentially, I need that property only to exist if the user is running iOS 6.

How does one handle this sort of situation?

Comment: Well, maintaining compatibility with iOS 4.3 is actually impossible now that armv6 cannot be compiled for, as the iPhone 3G can run iOS 4.3 and uses ARMv6. So you can't Do what you are requesting.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Except you can still select armv6 manually, and iOS 4.3 compatibility does not mean that you need to support the 3G.

Comment: As tc said, Richard is incorrect here; you can still select armv6, and I am currently compiling for iOS4.3 thru iOS6 without incident.

Comment: Errrr. actually not entirely correct.  Yes, you can target 4.3... but you can NOT in fact target armv6 devices if you're using the iOS 6 SDK.  So, you have to choose: Support new iOS 6 features (including the iPhone 5's form factor),  OR support iPhone 3G and iPod Touch 2G.  Can't do both.  Sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will just work. There's some metadata in the property/ivar that references the class name, but it doesn't actually link against the class or cause an error at runtime.

Of course, *always* test!

Comment: OK, feeling a little dumb now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `NSClassFromString` and `[UIDevice isSystemVersionHigherOrEqualTo:@"6.0"]`.

Comment: More useful would be to post how to use those functions to accomplish what the questioner asked.